# Monoids and groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, monoid

everybody. 
I got this exercise from Jacobson.

Let $M$ be a monoid generated by a set $S$ and suppose every element of $S$ is invertible. Show that $M$ is a group.

Proof:
every element of $M$ has the form $s_1,s_2,...,s_n$ which is invertible with inverse $s^{-1}_1,s^{-1}_2,...,s^{-1}_n \in M$. Hence, $M$ is a group.

Comment: There is at least one problem with what you've written: for example, why should $s_1^{-1}s_2^{-1}$ be the inverse of $s_1s_2$? After overcoming that, you could probably be a bit more thorough about your conclusion

Comment: @rschwieb because $s_1 s^{-1}_1$ = 1. Isn't enough?

Comment: that does not appear in the expression $s_1s_2s_1^{-1}s_2^{-1}$

Comment: $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1}$.